# Arraylist in reducer

Tags: java, arraylist, mapreduce

following is my reducer code. What i am supposed to do is to send arraylist from mapper to reducer and in reducer, want to print the values which are passed from mapper but problem is that in reducer it is not doing anything. It just comes to reducer, print "reducer" and do nothing. Please help to locate error.

```
public class firstreducer extends Reducer<LongWritable, IntArrayWritable, LongWritable, IntArrayWritable>
{

    public void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterable<IntArrayWritable> values, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {

        System.out.println("reducer");
        int[] sum = new int[2];

        for(IntArrayWritable val: values) {
            IntWritable[] temp = new IntWritable[2];
            temp = (val.get());

            for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                sum[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp[i].toString());
                System.out.println(sum[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What are the contents of `values`?

Comment: You need to use context.write() to send the values off to the reducer...

Comment: values are x-y coordinates @Jonny Henly